# How to make an svg have the same style as the images

Tags: html, css, svg, height

Here is my list of items :

```css
  .anim-box {
 margin-top: 5%;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.anim-box .item {
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 0 30%;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.anim-box .item svg,
.anim-box .item img {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-box">
   <div class="item"><img id="entry4" src="https://ykob.github.io/glsl-dissolve/img/osaka01.jpg"><span>spin</span></div>
   <div class="item"><img id="entry5" src="https://ykob.github.io/glsl-dissolve/img/osaka01.jpg" class="" style=""><span>zoom</span></div>
   <div class="item">
      <svg>
         <image xlink:href="https://ykob.github.io/glsl-dissolve/img/osaka01.jpg"></image>
      </svg>
      <span>svg</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here we have 3 items, the 1st and the 2nd ones are images with the exact same height/width/style. And the last item is an SVG with a different style from the other ones.

Please how can I make the style of the SVG to always be identical to the other ones ? (knowing that the image source is always the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a viewbox to set an aspect ratio to the SVG and it will behave the same as img:

```css
.anim-box {
 margin-top: 5%;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.anim-box .item {
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 0 30%;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.anim-box .item svg,
.anim-box .item img {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-box">
   <div class="item"><img id="entry4" src="https://ykob.github.io/glsl-dissolve/img/osaka01.jpg"><span>spin</span></div>
   <div class="item"><img id="entry5" src="https://ykob.github.io/glsl-dissolve/img/osaka01.jpg" class="" style=""><span>zoom</span></div>
   <div class="item">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 2048 1356">
         <image xlink:href="https://ykob.github.io/glsl-dissolve/img/osaka01.jpg"></image>
      </svg>
      <span>svg</span>
   </div>
</div>
```